# C# JSON deserialization of array/dictionary

Tags: c#, json, dictionary, serialization, javascriptserializer

I must consome web service (json).
I build a communication with serialization / deserialization with JavaScriptSerializer.

In 99% its works fine, but...
Error details is returned like that:

```
{"result":"FAIL","error":{"error_code":1,"desc":"INVALID_DATA","details":{"city":["City cannot be blank."]}}}
```

To handle that i created Class:

```
public class ErrorObj
{
    public int error_code { get; set; }
    public string desc { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string[]> details { get; set; }
}
```

But somtethimes 'details' is returned like that:

```
{"result":"FAIL","error":{"error_code":1,"desc":"ERROR_OPTIONS","details":["Specifying a bank account"]}}
```

or

```
{"result":"FAIL","error":{"error_code":1,"desc":"INVALID_DATA","details":[]}}
```

To handle thi the class should be like that:

```
public class ErrorObj
{
    public int error_code { get; set; }
    public string desc { get; set; }
    public string[] details { get; set; }
}
```

How to build object (`ErrorObj`) to handle all error messages?

Deserialization code:

```
public static T DeSerializeObjectFromJsonString<T>(string jsonString)
{
   T objectOut = default(T);
   Type outType = typeof(T);

   var obj = (T) new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize(jsonString, typeof(T));

  return obj;
}
```

Error message:

> System.InvalidOperationException : Type 
>   'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib, 
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],
>   [System.String[], mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]' is not supported for deserialization of an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use model object like this.

The `public Dictionary<string, string[]> details { get; set; }`, Just use **`dynamic`**  rather than `Dictionary<string, string[]>`.

Because the json string `detail` is unfixed.

```
public class Error
{
    public int error_code { get; set; }
    public string desc { get; set; }
    public dynamic details { get; set; }
}

public class ErrorObj
{
    public string result { get; set; }
    public Error error { get; set; }
}
```

If you want to know,which json did you get?

You can use `detail.GetType()`. To check the type is or isn't array.

like this simple

```
string DictJson = "{\"result\":\"FAIL\",\"error\":{\"error_code\":1,\"desc\":\"INVALID_DATA\",\"details\":{\"city\":[\"City cannot be blank.\"]}}}";

string ArrayJson = "{\"result\":\"FAIL\",\"error\":{\"error_code\":1,\"desc\":\"ERROR_OPTIONS\",\"details\":[\"Specifying a bank account\"]}}";

ErrorObj errorobj = DeSerializeObjectFromJsonString<ErrorObj>(ArrayJson);

if (errorobj.error.details.GetType().IsArray)
{
    //receive array detail
}
else
{
    //receive Dictionary<> detail
}
```

Comment: but when i use List<string>. I can not deserialize: "details":{"city":["City cannot be blank."]}

Comment: Ok! I modify my answer. You can try to use `dynamic`.

Comment: Thank You. Dynamic type is working fine. There are some work to handle all posible returned types, but it works :)

Comment: I glad it can help you :)

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly weird, because a webservice property should not change it type in different results.

You can handle it, by changing `details` type.

```
public JToken details { get; set; }
```

I would also suggest you to stick to C# naming convention and use `JsonProperty` attribute, for all properties.

```
[JsonProperty("details")]
public JToken Details { get; set; }
```

Comment: JToken i from JSON.NET not from JavaScriptSerializer?